Replace operation with value: how to reference the row number?
Imagine the following excel:

I now want to perform a replace operation like
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Replace What:="EMPTY", Replacement:="=B3", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True

but I want the replacement to contain a formula that references the row where the replacement happens. So I want EMPTY on row 3 to be replaced with the value in B3 and I want EMPTY on row 5 to be replaced with the value in B5.

Do you want replacing the string "EMPTY" with the value of B3? Or you want a solution to fill the gaps in series? I mean to complete missing 3 and 5 (being empty - nullString) from the serie 1 to 5?

It's an example. The basic question is: is there a way for my replacement value, a formula, to reference the row where the replace is taking place? It could a totally difference setup and my formula could be an IF in combination with OR's and AND's and even an XLOOKUP.

Why If or Or or something else if no need of any iteration? So, if I would say that you need to replace ONLY a specific string value from A:A with the value in B:B would it be a correct understanding? If you want an iteration, I also can show such a way...

To replace a specific string in A:A with the content from B:B, please try the next code. It evaluates a formula:
Sub REPLACEString()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
 Const searchStr As String = "EMPTY"
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A6")
 'to replace searchStr with value of the B:B column (the same row):
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A6")
 'to replace searchStr with value of the B:B column (the same row):
 rng.Value = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.address & "=""" & searchStr & """," & rng.Offset(, 1).address & "," & rng.address & ")")
End Sub

If you like iterating, you can use the next code:
Sub REPLACEString_Iteration()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i As Long
 Const searchStr As String = "EMPTY"
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A6")
 For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
    If rng.cells(i).Value = searchStr Then rng.cells(i).Value = rng.Offset(, 1).Value
 Next i
End Sub

A faster way when need to process huge ranges, try using an array like in the following code. Excel consumes time and resources on write on cells one at a time. Working with arrays, all processing is done extremely fast (in memory) and the processed result can be written at once, at the end of the code:
Sub REPLACEString_Array()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, arr, i As Long
 Const searchStr As String = "EMPTY"
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 arr = ws.Range("A2:B6").Value
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = searchStr Then arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 2) 'the array contains both columns!
 Next i
 'drop the processed array result back, at once:
 ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub


most helpful, thanks. In the iterating example, you reference <rng.Offset(, 1).Value>, this failed for me. I think it should be <rng.Cells(i).Offset(, 1).Value>. The array example is an excellent tip.

@user2638894 Yes, of coursr. I did not test it. I thought it's too simple... :)

There are ways to replace the value if it contains a spcific string, to replace all or only the respective part etc.

You can use R1C1 style referencing in the Replace method but you might have to switch to this referencing style first.
Here's a basic example to replace the cells in column A which contain "EMPTY" to a formula which refers to the value of the cell that is 1 column to its right:
Sub Switch_Reference_Style()

    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Replace _
        What:="EMPTY", _
        Replacement:="=RC[1]", _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        MatchCase:=True
    
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    
    
End Sub

